# getting rid of colon in grok

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Basically I was setting up an Elasticsearch-Logstash-Kibana (elk) stack for monitoring syslogs. Now I have to write the grok pattern for logstash.

Here's an example of my log:
`May  8 15:14:50 tileserver systemd[25780]: Startup finished in 29ms.`

And that's my pattern (yet):
`%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:zeit} %{HOSTNAME:host} %{SYSLOGPROG:program}`
Usually I'm also using `%{DATA:text}` for the message but it just works on the link below.

I'm using [Test grok patterns](https://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match) to test my patterns and these 3 work fine but there's the colon (from after PID) in front of the message and I don't want it to be there.
How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:zeit} %{HOSTNAME:host} %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_process}(:) %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick reply.   
Now I don't have the message anymore. That's my main problem. I don't want the colon but need the message.

Comment: oh sorry I had missunderstanding , I will edit the answer